# Finding ssrs matrix table coloumn values

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS matrix table, which generates column dynamically. but i want to add some static coloumn in that report(added manually). but the static columns will have the same value as one of the dynamic column. All i want to do is, find the specific dynamic column (a column name with DynamicColoumn1) and show it in this static column

```
=IIF(Fields!DynamicColumnData.Value = "DynamicColoumn1",Fields!DynamicColumnDataValue.Value, "")
```

this works only for the first data in the DynamicColumnData, not working for other values in the DynamicColumnData. Anyone faced similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this way

> ```
> =Sum(IIF(Fields!DynamicColumnData.Value = "DynamicColoumn1",
> Fields!DynamicColumnDataValue.Value, 0))
> ```

Not sure this is the efficient way of doing, but worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your formula to use the `First` dataset field only:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!DynamicColumnData.Value, "DataSet1") = "DynamicColoumn1",First(Fields!DynamicColumnDataValue.Value, "DataSet1"),  "")
```